# Harmonic Function in a half-disc

Tags: complex-analysis

In working through a book on complex variables, I came across this problem about showing a function is harmonic and I am not sure how to do that for this particular function. Thanks for any help.

Show the function $u(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\{P_r(t-\theta)-P_r(t+\theta)\}f(e^{it})dt$ is harmonic in the half-disc $\{re^{i\theta}:0<r<1,0<\theta<\pi)$ and satisfies the boundary conditions $$u(e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta}), 0<\theta<\pi$$ and $$u(x)=0, -1<x<1.$$

Comment: Should your limit of integration be $0$ to $2\pi$ or $\pi$? $t$ represents an angle so it seems like it should be bounded in some way. Additionally, what is $P$ here? Is it a harmonic function on the whole disk? It looks like the method of images is being applied here, which is why I ask.

Comment: What happens when you take $\Delta P(r,\theta)$? You need to justify taking the differentiation under the integral ...
@CameronWilliams $P$ is the Poisson kernel for the disc, it looks like.

Comment: @Ray, that makes complete sense. You're right. I just hadn't seen that notation before.